# Escape "(" and "'" into the awk -v FS argument

Tags: string, bash, unix, console, escaping

I have a file named: output.txt which I read line by line with the next code:

```
#!/bin/bash
outputFile=output.txt
while read line
do
    stringLine=$line
    echo $stringLine | awk -v FS='(include|string)' '{print $2}'    
done < $outputFile
```

A sample content of output.txt is:

```
sometext:include('js/jquery.ui.totop.js');
sometext:include('js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js');
```

I would like to extract the string between "include('" and "');"
but when I try to escape the "('" with:

```
echo $stringLine | awk -v FS="(include\(\'|string)" '{print $2}
```

It returns the next error:

```
awk: illegal primary in regular expression (include(|string) at string)
 input record number 1, file 
 source line number 1
```

Do you have any idea about how can I escape ( and ' in the FS argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the string `string` in your regex because there isn't a string `string` present in your input.

```
$ awk -v FS="include\\\('|'\\\)" '{print $2}' file
js/jquery.ui.totop.js
js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js
```

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly: 
`includeFile=$(echo $stringLine | awk -v FS="include\\\('|'\\\)" '{print $2}')`
that was the final line

Comment: i think you could do like `awk -v FS="include\\\('|'\\\)" '{print $2}' <<< "$stringLine"`

Answer (score 0):

In bash, `\` also escape characters in strings surrounded by `"`. Either use two backslashes, or change `"` to `'` and move original `'`s outside the string and change them to `\'`.